# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal component position

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, illegalargumentexception

I am working on the GUI code of a java Media Player here. When I try to run the main class, I keep getting the following error message :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegalcomponent position
       at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1085)
       at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:465)
       at dj2.gui.ArtistsPane.<init>(ArtistsPane.java:19)
       at dj2.gui.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:36)
       at dj2.test.GUITest.main(GUITest.java:21)
```

I think the problem comes from my ArtistsPane Class, since the two other errors are reference it.

Here is the code I am using for ArtistsPane :

```
public class ArtistsPane extends JPanel{

    public ArtistsPane(){

       this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       add(new TracksAddRemoveToolBar(),FlowLayout.TRAILING);}}
```

The problem is detected at the level of the add method.
What's wrong with it?
Thanks!

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: @AdrewThompson It seems like I can't post an image, I need 10 reputations for that :( Any ways to go around this rule? I am a newbie here..

Comment: *"Any ways to go around this rule?"*  Well, there is **ASCII art** as I already mentioned.  As far as images go, upload it to an image share site and provide a link.  If it is descriptive enough (and small enough) somebody else might embed it in the question.

Answer (score 6):

You use FlowLayout.TRAILING not when adding components but when defining the layout itself, and it belongs as a FlowLayout constructor parameter. So get rid of that bit of code from the add method.

e.g., change

```
public class ArtistsPane extends JPanel{

    public ArtistsPane(){

       this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       add(new TracksAddRemoveToolBar(),FlowLayout.TRAILING);}}
```

to

```
public class ArtistsPane extends JPanel{

    public ArtistsPane(){    
       setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
       add(new TracksAddRemoveToolBar());
    } // please place your brakcets with care
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I got read of the error by replacing the FlowLayout.TRAILING as you mentioned. I was trying to specify the alignment of the ToolBar within the frame. Any ideas in how to do this, please?

Comment: @NajwaLaabid: `" I was trying to specify the alignment of the ToolBar within the frame. Any ideas in how to do this, please?"` -- that would depend entirely on where *exactly* you wish to place the toolbar.